# Can someone help me understand this example of a phase space plot of an inverse SHO?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, phase-space

I can't quite grasp this particular phase plot. I am used to the momentum vs displacement plot that usually results in an ellipse, but I think this is trajectory vs displacement which I don't really understand. I have trouble reading the fine print of this textbook so if someone could please enlighten me I would be so grateful.

[image]

[image: Picture of the example]

Comment: Hint: How does this force compare to the usual Hooke's Law force? What does that imply about small displacements from equilibrium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've stated a familiarity with the case where a plot of $y=\dot{x}$ against $x$ obtains an ellipse, i.e. constant $y^2+\omega^2x^2$ for the normal SHO $\ddot{x}=-\omega^2x$. All this exercise does for the inverse SHO, where the ODE's $x$ coefficient has lost its $-$ sign, is update the quantity that stays constant throughout the system's time evolution. We can combine both exercises viz.$$\color{limegreen}{\ddot{x}}=\mp\omega^2\color{red}{x}\implies\frac{d}{dt}(\color{blue}{y}^2\pm\omega^2\color{red}{x}^2)=2(\color{blue}{y}\color{limegreen}{\dot{y}}\pm\omega^2\color{red}{x}\color{blue}{\dot{x}})=2\color{blue}{y}(\color{limegreen}{\ddot{x}}\pm\omega^2\color{red}{x})=0.$$(I've denoted $x$ and its first two derivatives red, blue and green.) So for the inverse SHO, instead of the trajectory being an ellipse $y^2+\omega^2x^2=C$, it's a hyperbola $y^2-\omega^2x^2=C$.